# R dataframe to matrix such that the colnames and rownames are from parameters

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to generate a matrix in R with rownames as a value in dataframe and colnames as so too. The values named by the row value and col value should match up with what's in the dataframe.

```
  p      photo filter     time
1  1 winter.png  edge1 94.51301
2  1  rocks.png  edge1 65.58044
3  1 pupper.png  edge1 47.72965
4  2 winter.png  edge1 57.73461
5  2  rocks.png  edge1 37.07482
6  2 pupper.png  edge1 26.07539
7  3 winter.png  edge1 39.93299
8  3  rocks.png  edge1 27.81006
9  3 pupper.png  edge1 18.99070
10 4 winter.png  edge1 33.10323
11 4  rocks.png  edge1 22.59480
12 4 pupper.png  edge1 15.38318
```

So for example I would like to produce something like:

```
             1          2          3        4
winter.png   94.51301   37.07482
rocks.png    65.58044   37.07482   27.81006     
pupper.png   47.72965   26.07539
```

(Not completely shown because I'm lazy)

Is there any good way for me to generate matrices as defined.

I want certain fields to placed in the `rownames` and `colnames` section of a matrix. That thing I can access with those functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: @PoGibas I looked at that answer, it didn't have the information I needed, because I'm trying to build a matrix that's filtered.

Comment: Filtered how? You don't mention that in your question.

Comment: @akrun You showed me the way to get it. Did not know about xtabs, That's a very cool function. You saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
     select(-filter) %>% 
     spread(p, time)
```

---

Or using `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(time ~ photo + p, df1)
```